# As of today (Solidity v0.4.22)... Is there a way to return structs from public functions?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, struct, encoding

https://medium.com/coinmonks/solidity-tutorial-returning-structs-from-public-functions-e78e48efb378

According to this article (link above), on Medium I'd have to use tuples... but this was so in Solidity v0.4.13 is possible now in v0.4.22 to do it without using tuples? Or do I still have to use tuples?
I've also seen an method that uses "experimental ABIEncoder" so is there a better way... what options are there to return structs from public functions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunately this

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract Demo {
    struct SimpleStruct {
        uint256 a;
        uint256 b;
        address c;
    }

    function returnsSimpleStruct() public view returns (SimpleStruct){
        return SimpleStruct(0, 0, address(0));
    }

}
```

does not compile witout `pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;`

Comment: Thanks @Henk, I think I'll just use the tuple method as this is still experimental...